# The id of root entities of the same kind

Tags: google-app-engine, objectify

The auto generated @Id Long id is said to be unique within specific parent. Does this mean that it is a possible for root entities of the same kind to have them same id. If this is true how do I ensure that root entities of the same kind dont have the same id.

Answer (score 2):

No, why would you think that? Root entities in effect have the same (null) parent, so they will all have unique IDs.